# How can I create convolutions or linear layers that operate on vectors rather than scalars in pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, matrix

Consider an `nn.Linear(2,3)` layer transform like the one below.  It uses a 2x3 matrix of scalar weights to create a weighted sum for each scalar element in the output.

Now suppose that instead of scalars I want to operate on 1d vectors (e.g. word embeddings).  So in this case `a` and `b` would be vectors and the weights `w` would each be square matrices.

Can one of the pre-built layer types in nn accomplish this (for linear or convolutions)?  Or is there some way to transform my data to accomplish the equivalent of this with the standard layer types?

thanks!

EDIT: I'm aware that for a given layer like the example I could just do all of the permutations of matrix operations and store the weights for them myself.  What I'm wondering is if there is a better way.

[image: enter image description]

EDIT: Ok, I think what I want does not exist but let me try to clarify on the hopes that maybe there is some similar operation...

Ignoring the bias vector `nn.Linear(2,3)` is doing the following:

[image]

What I'm looking for is the *analog* of this where a, b, c, ... are vectors and the weighting is a *linear transformation* of those vectors.  I apologize if my notation is off here but, written as row vectors:

[image]

This means that we'd need a 3 dimensional set of weights, not a 2d as in `nn.Linear`. Again, I guess this is just a different operation entirely but I'm wondering if this kind of thing has a name or if there is some reason it  isn't normally needed (e.g. some transformation of the data that really is equivalent to this).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question<sup>1</sup>, you'd like an input tensor of shape `(2, 3)`, where each element is actually a vector. If that is the case, you are essentially talking about a 3d tensor (instead of 2d).

For example, if each vector is 5 elements long, your input would have the shape `(2, 3, 5)`.

To compute convolutions over this, there are layers that take the dimensions as parameters - have a look at the Convolutional layers [**like Conv3d**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv3d).

To compute a linear layer on this input, you still just need to *flatten* or *reshape* the tensor to be a single vector.

If you vector lengths can vary, you will have to consider making them all match by either truncating them (making some shorter), or padding (adding e.g. zeros to make shorter ones longer) - or a mixture of both techniques.

---

<sup>1</sup> If I haven't fully understood, please add more details to the example in your question